# Flask class import error - Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app and I have written a custom api class to handle some api connections that Im trying to use in my flask app

The custom class is as follows:

```py
import request
import base64
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


class Rotaready:

    def __init__(self):
        self.org_id = 'MPRJ'
        self.token = None
```

The flask app looks like so:

```py
import os
import logging
from rotaready import Rotaready
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Message, Mail
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/dbname'

app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.mailtrap.io'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 2525
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'username'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = False
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = '_5#y2L"F4Q8zxec]/'

mail = Mail(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)
cors = CORS(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

logging.basicConfig(filename='demo.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I then load into pipenv shell and run flask run and I get

```
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised
```

I try and use the class as follows

```
@app.route('/test/rotaready', methods=['GET'])
def test_rotaready():
    rotaready = Rotaready()
    token = rotaready.create_connection()
    if token:
        return jsonify(message='Token Created Successfully'), 200
    else:
        return jsonify(message='Token issue'), 404
```

my pip file is as follows:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"
mysql-connector-python = "*"
flask-mysqldb = "*"
flask-jwt-extended = "*"
sqlalchemy = "*"
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
flask-mail = "*"
flask-cors = "*"
bcrypt-flask = "*"
requests = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

This is the output on the error and have no stack trace

```
E7440:/home/graham/Documents/development/kojo-backend-app# flask run  * Environment: development  * Debug mode: on Usage: flask run [OPTIONS] Try 'flask run --help' for help.  Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.
```

I hope thats all the information you will need

Comment: You omitted the most important: the full stack trace. It should provide more information and context. Show how you import `app` in your code. Very often, it is a path error due to the organization of files and directories.

Comment: All i get is ```(kojo-backend-app-tMeByA0R) root@graham-Latitude-E7440:/home/graham/Documents/development/kojo-backend-app# flask run
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.
```

Comment: try running `python app.py` instead of flask, that will probably give you more information to work with.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it after running python app.py I had an error on a f string and that was causing the import error!

So flask run for debugging wasnt great and running

```
python app.py
```

Was the way forward to debug any errors